# JavaScript check if value is only undefined, null or false

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

Other than creating a function, is there a shorter way to check if a value is `undefined`,`null` or `false` only in JavaScript?

**The below if statement is equivalent to `if(val===null && val===undefined val===false)`**
The code works fine, I'm looking for a shorter equivalent.

```
if(val==null || val===false){
  ;
}
```

Above `val==null` evaluates to true both when `val=undefined` or `val=null`.

I was thinking maybe using bitwise operators, or some other trickery.

Comment: What's wrong with: if (val){} ?

Comment: `''`,`0`,`'0'` and well several other configurations are true

Comment: if (val)  // null undefined false or 0

Comment: The `===` operator works great here, why are you using `==` when comparing to `null`?

Comment: I think you meant `if(!val)`.  In that case `''`,`0`,`'0'` and well several other values are `false`.

Comment: it also satisfies `undefined`

Comment: If you use `val === null` and add `val === undefined` it should work fine

Comment: Writing `val==null` is equivalent to writing `val===null && val===undefined`.  I'm trying to get a shorter syntax.

Comment: val === null and val === undefined are different - you will not get true for val === null if val is undefined.

Comment: @Brian `null==undefined` is true.  `val==null` is true both when val is `undefined` or `null`

Comment: I think this is the shortest you can get... or create your own function. Btw, `'0'` does **not** evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @Lime - give er' a whirl - lemme know what the prompt says... alert(null === undefined ? "Yep" : "Nope");

Comment: **@Felix** Thanks for the correction.  **@Brian** Did you read my comment or question?  I have always posted `==` not `===`.  give this a whirl :D `alert(null == undefined ? "Yep" : "Nope");`

Comment: @Lime - gotcha - I think the shortest you'll get here is if(val === undefined || !val), and that's going to count zeros as false, which I don't think you want...

Comment: This is a bit of a mess. If you arrive here like I did, just go read this: http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls:_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN

Comment: What's wrong with `if (!value)` ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, you can always "give up" :)

```
function b(val){
    return (val==null || val===false);
}
```

Comment: Well I piratically gave up, but did end up changing `false` to `!1`

Comment: I think we can change val === false to val == false :)

Comment: @Konza: [That just how `==` is defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons#359509). Its fairly complicated and its why many people recommend using `===` unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: doesnot work 
better can be used as 

 if(typeof variable_here === 'undefined'){
   // your code here.
 };

Comment: It's crazy but for me it doesn't worw with `null` but with `'null'` !! And also not work with `val == ''` (tested both in firefox console and live....if you have a clue ?

Comment: thats strange. you might want to create a separate question thread for that.

Comment: piratically - adv. do do something as pirate would...

Answer (score 20):

I think what you're looking for is **`!!val==false`** which can be turned to **`!val`** (even shorter):

You see:

```
function checkValue(value) {
    console.log(!!value);
}

checkValue(); // false
checkValue(null); // false
checkValue(undefined); // false
checkValue(false); // false
checkValue(""); // false

checkValue(true); // true
checkValue({}); // true
checkValue("any string"); // true
```

That works by flipping the value by using the `!` operator.

If you flip `null` once for example like so :

```
console.log(!null) // that would output --> true
```

If you flip it twice like so :

```
console.log(!!null) // that would output --> false
```

Same with `undefined` or `false`.

Your code:

```
if(val==null || val===false){
  ;
}
```

would then become:

```
if(!val) {
  ;
}
```

That would work for all cases even when there's a string but it's length is zero.
Now if you want it to also work for the number 0 (which would become `false` if it was double flipped) then your if would become:

```
if(!val && val !== 0) {
  // code runs only when val == null, undefined, false, or empty string ""
}
```

Comment: You forget 0 and ''

Comment: Updated the answer to also take into account strings and the number zero 0.

Answer (score 18):

The best way to do it I think is:

```
if(val != true){
//do something
}
```

This will be true if val is false, NaN, or undefined.

Comment: This techique is probably the best disregarding the NaN value.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

Based on the document, Boolean object will return true if the value is not 0, undefined, null, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

> If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false.

So

```
if(Boolean(val))
{
//executable...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is like that:

```
var acceptable = {"undefined": 1, "boolean": 1, "object": 1};

if(!val && acceptable[typeof val]){
  // ...
}
```

I think it minimizes the number of operations given your restrictions making the check fast.

Answer (score 1):

only shortcut for something like this that I know of is

```
var val;
(val==null || val===false) ? false: true;
```

Comment: @missingno can't see why not... it's shorter than writing out `if ... else ...` and in any case, how shorter can you get a conditional statement like this? ... better answer than "just give up" imo >.>

Comment: All your conditional does is convert things to a boolean. However, this can be done much succintely with `!!` or, in this case, by doing nothing at all as the consition already is a boolean.

Comment: @missingno no no no.... any code you want to execute based on the condition would go *in place of* the `false` and `true`... those are just there for clarity sake as to what results in what

Comment: Some people consider this as bad style. The ternary operator should be used to return a value, not for it's side effects.

Comment: I would add functions where the `false` and `true` are then.  Now it just appears as being over engineered.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean(val) === false.  This worked for me to check if value was falsely.

Comment: But that will also be true for `0` or `""`. Also, Yiding already provided this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using ? is much cleaner.

```
var ? function_if_exists() : function_if_doesnt_exist();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like Below

```
var Boolify = require('node-boolify').Boolify;
if (!Boolify(val)) {
    //your instruction
}
```

Refer [node-boolify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-boolify)