# Is it possible to check for null inline in javascript?

Tags: javascript, null

I have a function which parses the address components of the Google Maps API  `JSON` and then returns the city / locality / route name.

The `getAddressComponent()` returns a `null` if it cannot find the key.

`let route = getAddressComponent(addressComponents, 'route').value.long_name;`

So let's say it didn't find the key, then I get a `Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'long_name' of undefined` obviously because it's not defined.

How do I check for `null` in javascript other than the conditional method `(a === null)`?

How can I simply check like this with `?`

EDIT : Safe Navigation Operator

`let route = getAddressComponent(addressComponents, 'route')?.value.long_name;`

And if it doesn't exists, it could probably set `route` to `null` instead of throwing a Error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript check if value is only undefined, null or false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836865/javascript-check-if-value-is-only-undefined-null-or-false)

Comment: Is getAddressComponent async or not?

Comment: Do you mean `(element != null ? element.value.long_name : null)`?

Comment: @mplungjan No it is not

Comment: @GalAbra No, I meant if I could somehow do something like this https://tc39.github.io/proposal-optional-chaining/

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Sorry, It returns null

Answer (score 140):

## 2020 Answer, It Exists!!!

You can now directly use `?.` inline to test for existence. It is called the **`Optional Chaining Operator`**, supported by all modern browsers.

If a property exists, it proceeds to the next check, or returns the value. Any failure will immediately short-circuit and return `undefined`.

```
const example = {a: ["first", {b:3}, false]}

example?.a  // ["first", {b:3}, false]
example?.b  // undefined

example?.a?.[0]     // "first"
example?.a?.[1]?.a  // undefined
example?.a?.[1]?.b  // 3

domElement?.parentElement?.children?.[3]?.nextElementSibling
```

To ensure a default defined value, you can use `??`. If you require the first truthy value, you can use `||`.

```
example?.c ?? "c"  // "c"
example?.c || "c"  // "c"

example?.a?.[2] ?? 2  // false
example?.a?.[2] || 2  // 2
```

If you do not check a case, the left-side property must exist. If not, it will throw an exception.

```
example?.First         // undefined
example?.First.Second  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Second' of undefined
```

[`?.` Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining) - 94%, Oct '22

[`??` Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing) - 94%

[Node Support](https://medium.com/@nodejs/node-js-version-14-available-now-8170d384567e) - v14+

Comment: Sadly you cannot do `?? throw new Error("...")`.

Answer (score 32):

## Update 2020

This long-wished feature is now available in JavaScript!

I'll redirect to [Gibolt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823932/479251), which covers it well.

## Original 2018 answer

- **There is no "null-safe  navigation operator" in Javascript** (EcmaScript 5 or 6), like `?.` in C#, Angular templates, etc. (also sometimes called Elvis operator, when written `?:`)  , at least yet, unfortunately.
- You can test for `null` and return some dependent expression in a single line **with the ternary operator** `?:`, as already given in other answers :

(use `=== null` to check only for `null`s values, and `== null` to check for `null` *and* `undefined`)

```
    console.log(myVar == null ? myVar.myProp : 'fallBackValue');
```

- in some cases, like yours, when your variable is supposed to hold an `object`, you can **simply use the fact that any object is** *truthy* whereas `null` and `undefined` are *falsy* values :

  ```
    if (myVar) 
        console.log(myVar.myProp)
    else
        console.log('fallbackValue')
  ```

  You can test for falsy values by coalescing to boolean with `!!` and make this inline :

  ```
    console.log(!!myVar ? myVar.myProp : 'fallbackValue');
  ```

  Be very careful though with this "falsy test", for if your variable is `0`, `''`, or `NaN`, then it is *falsy* as well, even though it is not null/undefined.

Answer (score 10):

Code below simplified `return num ? num : 0` for me:

`return num || 0;`

As of today more correct semantically;

`return num ?? 0`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Assuming num is of type int, then `return num || 0` is equivalent to `return num` ...

Comment: the question tags are javascript and null. I wouldn't assume it is int :)

Answer (score 4):

```
let component = getAddressComponent(addressComponents, 'route');
let route = component ? component : null
```

you can use the `?` operator to check the value is `true` or `false`  then set the value in javascript `null` will be `false`

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a null coalescent operator.
Javascript doesn't have one. Most of the time peoples use the logical OR `||` for this purpose but it doesn't work on property access.

There's proposal for adding null coalescing to the language, but it's nowhere near:
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing
https://tc39.github.io/proposal-nullish-coalescing/

If you really, really, absolutly want to use it you can use this Babel plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining
But I would strongly suggest you don't: this may never make it to the language and you would have unvalid code in your codebase.

Answer (score 3):

For empty strings you can use `!`:

```js
var foo = 'yo';
console.log(!foo);

var foo = null;
console.log(!foo);
```

And for the `?` you asked about, it's the [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), the syntax is `condition ? if true : if false` you can use it as follows:

```js
var foo = 'yo';
console.log('1 : ' + (!foo ? 'Null' : 'Not Null'));
console.log('2 : ' + (foo === null ? 'Null' : 'Not Null'));
console.log('3 : ' + (foo == null ? 'Null' : 'Not Null'));

var foo = null;
console.log('1 : ' + (!foo ? 'Null' : 'Not Null'));
console.log('2 : ' + (foo === null ? 'Null' : 'Not Null'));
console.log('3 : ' + (foo == null ? 'Null' : 'Not Null'));
```

Comment: Note that "empty string" is not the same as "null value", but they are both *falsy* when coerced to Boolean (like when you apply `!`, or in a `if`). `var foobar = ''; console.log((!foobar ? 'falsy like null' : 'not falsy')); console.log((foobar === null ? '===Null' : '!==Null')); console.log((foobar == null ? '==Null' : '!=Null'));` .

Answer (score 0):

`.?` cannot be used in javascript, for that, you might look into typescript.

For example, you can use `try...catch` construction:

```
let route

try {
  route = getAddressComponent(addressComponents, 'route').value.long_name
} catch (error) {
  route = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to [jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558778/jeroen):

You can not `?? throw new Error("...")`. But you can do:

```js
const throwError = (missingParam) => { throw new Error(`Parameter ${missingParam} is missing`); };

{
    someParam: a.anotherParam ?? throwError('anotherParam')
}
```