# What does ?. and ?? operator in javascript do?

Tags: javascript, operators

I recently noticed usage like this in a java script code base what does it do. I was unable to find any relevant documentation regarding that. Though intuitively operators seem to checking whether property is present. Is there any official documentation regarding this.

Ex:

```
args?.propertyName !== 'someValue'
const value = props.someProp ?? props.defaultProp;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341869/is-it-possible-to-check-for-null-inline-in-javascript/

Comment: `?.` refers to optional chaining.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to check for null inline in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341869/is-it-possible-to-check-for-null-inline-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?.` is called the optional chaining operator ([TC39 Stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)), it is used when you are not sure whether a nested property exists or not. If you try to use the `.` operator to access a property which is `undefined` you get a `TypeError`.

For example:

```
const obj = {foo: {} };

//This is safe, results in undefined
console.log(obj?.foo?.bar?.baz);

//This results in Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baz' of undefined
console.log(obj.foo.bar.baz);
```

Where as the `??` is called the null coalescing operator ([TC39 Stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing)). When you are using falsy values like an empty string `""` or a `0` with a `||` operator the operand on the right hand side of the `||` is returned as the falsy value is ignored.

The `??` comes handy when you don't want that and actually you want to consider the falsy values. If the value on the left is a `null` or `undefined` only then the value on the right of the `??` is taken:

For example:

```
const empString = "";
const defaultValue = empString || "A default value";
//Outputs A default value as "" empty string is falsy
console.log(defaultValue);

const actualValue = empString ?? "A default value";
//Does not print the default value as the empString is neither null or undefined
console.log(actualValue);
```

Same for other falsy values like `0`, `false`, in disagreement with the `||` operator which will output the `'default` string:

```
console.log(false ?? 'default') //false

console.log(0 ?? 'default') // 0
```

Only for `undefined` and `null` this will output the default value provided in agreement with the `||` operator:

```
console.log(undefined ?? 'default') //default

console.log(null ?? 'default') //default
```

Answer (score 2):

They are for optionals:

`val ?? other` is called nullish coalescing operator and is equivalent to `val == null ? other : val`

and `optionalThing?.property` is refered as optional chaining and is the same as `optionalThing == null ? null : optionalThing.property`

This optional chaining expressions result in shorter and simpler expressions when accessing chained properties when the possibility exists that a reference may be missing ( allows you to do things like `optionalThing?.optionalProperty?.anotherOptionalProperty?.property` ).